# The driver is not executable chromedriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

When I try to build the maven project, happened the error below.

[ERROR] beforeMethod(test.HomeTest)  Time elapsed: 0.308 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/autocred-ui-automated-tests/workspace/autocredenciamento/chromedriver
    at test.HomeTest.beforeMethod(HomeTest.java:19)

PS: The jenkins server are hosted on CentOS.

Comment: What are the the file permissions? `ls -l /var/lib/....../chromedriver`

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 7874704 Mar 26 17:58 /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/autocred-ui-automated-tests/workspace/autocredenciamento/chromedriver

Comment: How did you get the chromedriver over to Jenkins? Please do not respond to questions in Comments, but update your original post with additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Make chromedriver executable

```
chmod +x /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/autocred-ui-automated-tests/workspace/autocredenciamento/chromedriver
```

Maybe you'll need root's privileges

```
sudo chmod +x /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/autocred-ui-automated-tests/workspace/autocredenciamento/chromedriver
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of .exe extension that is given to the chrome driver.

```
public static String driverpath = "/home/ubuntu/KrishnasworkDIR/Jarss/chromedriver";
```

this worked for me. Also check read and write permission for the chromedriver.